# How to Merge GA4 Data with Campaign Manager in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

The main issue I'm facing involves integrating data from Google Analytics 4 (GA4) with data from Campaign Manager in Google BigQuery. I have successfully transferred both datasets directly into BigQuery, but the challenge arises when trying to merge them. Specifically, I'm struggling to identify a common field or variable that can be used to effectively join these tables. My goal is to create a unified table that combines GA4's campaign performance metrics with Campaign Manager's data to gain a comprehensive view of campaign effectiveness. I am looking for advice on which fields are best suited for this purpose and any successful SQL query examples that might have been used in similar scenarios.

So far, I have tried various basic SQL queries to merge the data, using fields that I thought might be common between GA4 and Campaign Manager, such as campaign identifiers and dates. I expected these queries to allow me to create a table with an integrated view of the metrics from both platforms. However, the results have not been as expected. The queries have failed to effectively join the data, resulting in an incomplete or inconsistent table. This leads me to believe that I have not identified the correct field for joining the data or that I need a more advanced approach to the SQL query.